# Determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent. $\int^{\infty}_1 81\frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent.$\int^{\infty}_1 81\frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx$

My answer is $\infty-0=\infty$

But I am unsure whether it is convergent or divergent.

Comment: The "answer" $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: Thus it is divergent?

Comment: @Cetshwayo Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant $81$ is irrelevant, so we can just consider
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx
$$
The integral converges if and only if
$$
\int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}\,dx
$$
converges. Since $\ln x\ge1$ for $x\ge e$, we have
$$
\frac{\ln x}{x}\ge\frac{1}{x}
$$
However
$$
\int_e^\infty\frac{1}{x}\,dx
$$
does not converge, because $\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln x=\infty$, therefore also the given integral is divergent.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Observe that, for $x>0$,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln x \right)^2=2\frac{\ln x}{x}
$$ and that, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\left(\ln x \right)^2 \to \infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

An antiderivative of the integrand is:
\begin{align}
\int 81 \frac{\ln(x)}{x} dx 
&= 81 \frac{\ln(x)^2}{2} + C
\end{align}

We have $\ln(1) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln(x) = \infty$.
This gives
\begin{align}
\int\limits_1^\infty 81 \frac{\ln(x)}{x} dx &= 
\frac{81}{2}\left[\ln(x)^2\right]_{x=1}^{x \to \infty} \\ 
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{81}{2} \ln(x)^2 = \infty
\end{align}

Comment: Where does this $81$ come from? :-)

Comment: @Math-fun An arbitrary edit removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that the integral is divergent by Bertrand criterion where here $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=-1.$

Comment: Looking at the [EoM article](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bertrand_criterion), I can guess that $\beta$ is the limit $B$ there. What is $\alpha$?